# Viable way to predict memory usage of a huge process, after a few steps in a loop

Tags: php, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a process with uses many memory, and this process runs inside a loop which may have
something like 100 iterations. For each iterations, the process consumes ~3Mb, and the php
garbage collector does not seem to be able to free this memory between each iteration.

I first tried to free this leaking memory (by unsetting some choosen variables, or setting them to `null`), but in vain.

So, as a workaround **I would like the process to exit gracefully *before* crashing**, in order
to keep the database clean. So I try to predict, as precisely as possible, when it's time to
stop in order to prevent a memory crash.

To achieve this, I used `memory_get_usage()` and started debugging what was happenning. With this method I
finally saw that after each iteration, around 3Mb of memory was leaking.
But when the memory crash happens, there is still about 37Mb of memory remaining, which seems to
indicate that the inner process needs this amount of memory to run (~37Mb of allocated memory, then
only ~34Mb freed).

Considering that the first iterations will always work, how can I predict more precisely how much
real memory is needed to perform one step? I hoped `memory_get_peak_usage()` would give the right
information (e.g. `memory_get_usage()` + ~37Mb), but weirdly, the returned value is always lower than `memory_get_usage()`.

EDIT: to explain it differently, my goal is to stop the execution *before* the memory limit has been reached. But limiting to a fixed number of iterations is not very precise: what I want is to **guess** (approximately) when the memory reaches a critical amount, then stop the execution gracefully.

```
$memoryAnalysis = new MemoryAnalysis();
echo "\n";
echo "####### INITIAL MEMORY: ".$memoryAnalysis->getMemoryUsage(true)."\n";
echo "####### INITIAL MEMORY PEAK: ".$memoryAnalysis->getMemoryPeakUsage(true)."\n";
echo "\n";

foreach ($mails as $n => $mail) {

    // ... PERFORM HUGE PROCESS ...

    $memoryAnalysis->newStep();
    echo "\n";
    echo "####### LOOP $n\n";
    echo "####### Memory: ".$memoryAnalysis->getMemoryUsage(true)."\n";
    echo "####### Memory peak: ".$memoryAnalysis->getMemoryPeakUsage(true)."\n";
    echo "####### Average memory per step: ".$memoryAnalysis->getMemoryUsagePerStep(true)."\n";
    echo "####### Average memory peak per step: ".$memoryAnalysis->getMemoryPeakUsagePerStep(true)."\n";
}
```

Here is the code for the `MemoryAnalysis` class:

```
class MemoryAnalysis
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $nbSteps;
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $initialMemoryUsage;
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $initialMemoryPeakUsage;

    /**
     * MemoryAnalysis constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->nbSteps = 0;
        $this->initialMemoryUsage = memory_get_usage();
        $this->initialMemoryPeakUsage = memory_get_peak_usage();
    }

    /**
     * Add a new step after a huge memory use has been done.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function newStep(): void
    {
        $this->nbSteps++;
    }

    /**
     * Return the amount of used memory since the creation of the objecT.
     *
     * @param bool $formatted Return a formatted string instead of an integer
     *
     * @return int|string
     */
    public function getMemoryUsage(bool $formatted = false)
    {
        $mem = memory_get_usage() - $this->initialMemoryUsage;

        return $formatted ? self::format($mem) : $mem;
    }

    /**
     * Return the average memory usage per step.
     *
     * @param bool $formatted Return a formatted string instead of an integer
     *
     * @return int|string|null Null if no step was added
     */
    public function getMemoryUsagePerStep(bool $formatted = false)
    {
        if ($this->nbSteps < 0) {
            return null;
        }

        $mem = $this->getMemoryUsage() / $this->nbSteps;

        return $formatted ? self::format($mem) : $mem;
    }

    /**
     * Return the amount of used memory since the creation of the objecT.
     *
     * @param bool $formatted Return a formatted string instead of an integer
     *
     * @return int|string
     */
    public function getMemoryPeakUsage(bool $formatted = false)
    {
        $mem = memory_get_peak_usage() - $this->initialMemoryPeakUsage;

        return $formatted ? self::format($mem) : $mem;
    }

    /**
     * Return the average memory usage per step.
     *
     * @param bool $formatted Return a formatted string instead of an integer
     *
     * @return int|string|null Null if no step was added
     */
    public function getMemoryPeakUsagePerStep(bool $formatted = false)
    {
        if ($this->nbSteps === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        $mem = $this->getMemoryPeakUsage() / $this->nbSteps;

        return $formatted ? self::format($mem) : $mem;
    }

    /**
     * Format a long number in a readable way.
     *
     * @param int $n Number
     *
     * @return string String separated by commas
     */
    public static function format(int $n): string
    {
        $n = (string) $n;
        $len = strlen($n);
        $nbGroups = (int) floor(($len - 1) / 3);
        $output = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i !== $nbGroups + 1; $i++) {
            $start = $len - ($i + 1) * 3;
            $groupLen = min(3, $start + 3);
            $start = max(0, $start);
            $group = substr($n, $start, $groupLen);
            $output = ',' . $group . $output;
        }

        return substr($output, 1);
    }
}
```

And here the output I get:

```
####### INITIAL MEMORY: 408
####### INITIAL MEMORY PEAK: 0

####### LOOP 0
####### Memory: 15,222,912
####### Memory peak: 15,347,416
####### Average memory per step: 15,222,912
####### Average memory peak per step: 15,347,416

####### LOOP 1
####### Memory: 18,449,320
####### Memory peak: 18,506,312
####### Average memory per step: 9,224,660
####### Average memory peak per step: 9,253,156

####### LOOP 2
####### Memory: 21,043,056
####### Memory peak: 21,073,976
####### Average memory per step: 7,014,352
####### Average memory peak per step: 7,024,658

####### LOOP 3
####### Memory: 23,620,488
####### Memory peak: 23,629,968
####### Average memory per step: 5,905,122
####### Average memory peak per step: 5,907,492

[...]

####### LOOP 30
####### Memory: 89,779,456
####### Memory peak: 89,837,232
####### Average memory per step: 2,896,111
####### Average memory peak per step: 2,897,975

####### LOOP 31
####### Memory: 97,670,280
####### Memory peak: 97,713,624
####### Average memory per step: 3,052,196
####### Average memory peak per step: 3,053,550
```

The loop breaks here and shows the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/options-resolver/OptionsResolver.php on line 805
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/OutOfMemoryException.php on line 1
```

*NOTE*: the memory consumption average could be more precise by skipping the first step, which takes really more memory than the next ones. But my question is more about this "invisible" memory usage of about ~37Mb in the example, that I don't know how to predict.

**EDIT 2**: thanks to the advices given by sintakonte in the comments, the memory consumption has been divided by 3. But the question remains open.

Comment: _the php garbage collector does not seem to be able to free this memory between each iteration_ - imho it might be more helpful to show your code in order to analyze it - instead of discussing about your memory class.

Comment: Could you not batch your processes and only perform a certain fixed amount of processes per execution (instead of iterating until it fails)? This probably wouldn't be a solution if the memory usage per iteration varies wildly, but if they are roughly the same and it usually fails after 10 iterations, do 8 iterations.

Comment: Also have you looked at `gc_collect_cycles` (https://www.php.net/gc_collect_cycles)

Comment: @sintakonte: unfortunately I can't show the process code for 2 reasons: 1. it's a huge symfony project and the process uses dozens of different classes; 2. it's company private code. Note: I just showed the memory class in order to show my use of the php memory functions, but you're right: it's not the discussion.

Comment: @BrettGregson: it's exactly what I want to do: limiting to a certain amount of processes per execution. But limiting to a fixed number of iterations is not very precise: what I want is to guess (approximately) the limit before the process must be stopped, because it reaches memory limits.

Comment: I tried using `gc_collect_cycles()`, without success: it actually collects cycles, but the memory consumption is similar.

Comment: You memory consumption rises in a linear way - in any iteration it looks like you need ~ `2.6` MB - so you dont release anything in your loop - which means you have to adapt your code within the loop. since you are not be willing to share your code i take a wild guess: maybe https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php helps

Comment: @sintakonte a few days ago I debugged to code more deeply, I found out that many memory was used by doctrine, e.g. form validations, form building. Maybe buffered queries also use memory; but after a few unsuccessful hours I had to go on and find a solution; that's why now I'm posting the present question, even if correcting the memory leak would be the best solution, indeed.

Comment: if it is db related - you should be able to solve it - because doctrine supports unbuffered queries - and it really looks like this is your bottleneck (take a looker at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results)

Comment: By using `$em->clear()`, the number of iterations before crashing grows from 31 to 104, really better. Though there is still a 1MB leak per iteration.

Comment: Please review PHP's discussion of garbage collection https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php ... it sounds to me like there is a more fundamental reason *(read: "a bug in your code")* which is preventing the garbage collector from reaping.  Perhaps the collector concludes that all of this memory is still in use.  This can occur, for instance, when structures reference one another.  See the discussion of "weak references" at https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.weakref.php ... these allow you to indicate references that the garbage collector is allowed to disregard in its hunt for loops.

Comment: To clarify the above comment:  if `a` refers to `b` which refers to `a`, this creates a loop which can cause the garbage collector to decide that the object can't be freed, even though there are no remaining references to either `a` or `b`.  If you *weaken* one or both of the references, however, the garbage collector will not count them as it decides whether `a` and/or `b` can be freed.  It can now reap, and the memory leak is thereby solved.  (If it does decide to reap, it will set the references to Null.)

Comment: @MikeRobinson Indeed, I guess there are many "fundamental reasons" in this big project;) Weak references seem to be a very plausible way of fixing the problem. But as I explained earlier, I need to find a solution close to the Brett Gregson's comment (limited amount of processes per execution)